# Finding delay in a cosine signal

Tags: signal

Is there a delay (or phase shift ) in the following cosine signal?
[image]

If yes, how to find delay in a signal? Will appreciate your help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: that's not a cosine signal. So, not even close what to answer here. As always, start by writing down your signal as function of time or sample number, i.e. \$x(n)=???\$.

Comment: That's not a cosine signal. However, it does appear to be periodic. The strongest component is peaking at time zero, so it looks like that component is cosine with no phase shift. I'm getting a hint of a 1/7th subharmonic in there, and there are a few others in there as well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I forgot to include the amplitude spectrum, I guess x(n) should be 0.5*cos(2*pi*3/200 + q) + 1.5*cos(2*pi*7/200 + q), where q is the phase shift. But, I am not sure how to calculate the phase shift?

Comment: There hasn't been even a single comment which can answer my simple question! Sorry to say but, if you can't help please don't put a downvote or discourage others from asking valid question:)

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 um, if it was a "simple question", why would you be asking it? and: why do you have an amplitude spectrum, but not a phase spectrum?

Comment: @MarcusMüller well if you know the answer, why not simply explain me!

Comment: Because your question is impossible to answer, as I've already told you in the comments to the answer: a multi-tone signal doesn't have a single absolute phase, which is kind of logical.

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 Either fix your question by editing it or deal with it being downvoted and closed. Complaining in the comments that we aren't answering an un-answerable question is beyond silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosine is sine but shifted in time 1/4 cycle. Your signal is a sum of at least 2 sinusoidal signals with different frequencies. Fourier transform can help to decide the frequencies, amplitudes and phase angles but if you have only this short sample the result is very inaccurate.

ADD due the edit in the question

The questioner has added that he knows there's 2 frequency components. He knows the frequencies and amplitudes, only phases (or delays as he says) are unknown. This starts to sound homework, so no ready to use answer is given.

You can find the phase angles with QI-mixing. That's the general technique to present a sine as sum of orthogonal vector components; essential in data communication. That mixing is actually equal with calculating one frequency component of the Fourier transform.

Or you can force Excel solver to fit the phase angles to the time series.

I guessed by watching your image and formula (fixed to form X(n)=0.5*cos(2n*pi*3/200 + q) + 1.5*cos(2n*pi*7/200 + q) that the number q is zero. But there's only the image accuracy available.

Plotting that guess in Excel gave this:

[image]

When scaled your plot to the same size and placed together in Photoshop for comparison I can say that q=0 is as good guess as the screen resolution makes possible.

[image]

Numeric data would give more accuracy.

Comment: I forgot to include the amplitude spectrum, I guess x(n) should be 0.5*cos(2*pi*3/200 + q) + 1.5*cos(2*pi*7/200 + q), where q is the phase shift. But, I am not sure how to calculate the phase shift?

Comment: I don't get what's the point of help if you can't even tell if there is a phase shift in the graph or not!

Comment: I am not asking you to solve my homework, I am jusk asking a doubt which I encountered while dealing with this probelm! I think the purpose of this site is to clear doubts that's why it's up there!

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 only a single cosine can have a phase, a sum of different harmonic oscillations doesn't have one. You're very high and mighty for someone who isn't able to answer what they call "a simple question" themselves.